# setter method giving an error due to this keyword

Tags: java, class, methods, this, setter

The program is throwing an error in the setter method possibly due to the use of this keyword. Why is it giving an error?

The error: Method call setAge(-5), set a field value of "-5" but "0" was expected.expected: <0> but was: <-5>.

```
public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;

    public String getFirstName(){

        return this.firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName(){

        return this.lastName;
    }

    public int getAge(){

        return this.age;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName){

        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName){

        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setAge(int age){

        **if(age < 0 || age > 100){
            this.age = 0;** *Why this keyword gives an error here?*
        }
       
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: The last line of the setter _always_ gets executed. Add a `return;` in the `if` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change   your set age function to :

```
public void setAge(int age){

        if(age < 0 || age > 100){
            this.age = 0;
        }
        else
            this.age = age;
       
       
    }
```

or

```
public void setAge(int age){

        if(age < 0 || age > 100){
            age = 0;
        }
       
        this.age = age;
    }
```

Comment: Why are we not using "this" in the second snippet? <age = 0>

Comment: because this.age = 0;
change  the attribut instance not the variable passed in the parameter 
its true that  it changed it  to 0 
but later 
in the next line 
it still execute 
this.age=age;
which means 
u will overwrite the 0 that you wrote  and change it to  the variable passed  in the parameter